# PHP CLI is installed and working..but wont run script?

Tags: php, path, command-line-interface, centos6.5

So I have tried everything I can think of to get this working. First of all this is NOT just an issue with 1 script, I have tried 3 or 4 of the scripts I normally use and I cannot get any of them to run on this server. I believe PHP CLI is working, both because I can run commands but also because I can see arguments required for php files without the keyword. PHP -v output

```
PHP 5.6.25 (cli) (built: Oct 21 2016 18:00:07)
Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies
```

As you can see it spits out php version and cli.
On my script itself I have added the following shebang at various times

```
#!/opt/rh/rh-php56/root/usr/bin/php
#!/usr/local/bin/php
#!/usr/bin/php
#!/usr/bin/env php
```

Finally if I try and run my script this is what happens.

```
[root@VM_0_5_centos misc]# ./english_to_chinese_dictionary.php
  Usage:
     english_to_chinese_dictionary.php server user password customer mappingFileLocation
```

Because of it outputting my "Usage" string I am pretty sure it is reading the file. If I however actually type all of the required arguments, then I get "No such file directory[root@VM_0_5_centos]" Every, single, time.

Bonus info, I have also run chmod 0777 on the file and I have tried setting the permissions to the correct user and running as root.

Any ideas?

Comment: try `[root@VM_0_5_centos misc]# php ./english_to_chinese_dictionary.php`

Answer (score 0):

Specifing the interpreter and running directly always brought problems to me. To check if it's a script problem rather than interpreter try removing all interpreter info, leave just `<?php //code....` in it. Then run the script with `php -f filename.php` you won't need any execution or write permissions on the file.

I add that I usually prefer this way beacause it works perfectly on all platforms, including Windows PHP cli (obviously if the script is compatible)